# Is rand() predictable in C++

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the Right Way to use the rand() Function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117292/whats-the-right-way-to-use-the-rand-function-in-c)

When I run the below program I always get the same values each time.  Is rand not a true random function?

```
int main()
{

 while(1)
 {
 getch();
 cout<<rand()<<endl;
 }

}
```

In each run I am getting the below values.

41

18467

6334

26500

19169

15724

......

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: @aaa: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @mmy i thought links only go in comment?

Comment: @aaa: they can go in an answer also. You should do that. You'll get more credit for it there.

Comment: Thanks all, Thanks for link, I need to initialize random seed
  srand ( );

to get different numbers..Thanks a lot again for link

Comment: @aaa: Links to existing SO content should go in comments (for informative purposes or so we can vote to close as a duplicate). Links to outside resources should go into answers with a summary of what it says on the other side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718854/correct-use-of-s-rand-or-boostrandom

Comment: It's actually not a bug. Reproductability is a feature to ease debugging and tests. For example, I would point you toward Boost.Random library, when describing the generators it's explicitly stated that they should provide the same output if run in the same conditions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes and no. rand() is a pseudo random number generator that will always return the same sequence of numbers given the same seed value. Typically one 'seeds' the random number generator with some random data and then uses rand() to return a sequence of seemingly random numbers. If your random data isn't needed for something requiring 'true' randomness (such as cryptography based security) just using the current system time is sufficient. However, if you are using it for security purposes, look into obtaining more truly random data from entropy gathering utilities and use that to seed the random number generator.

As aa mentioned, the seed function is referenced [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/)

Comment: For cyptography, ensure your random number generator is suitable -- the requirements are somewhat different to other random number uses. Better still, use one from your OS, or an established library like cyrpto++. If you create your own you will likely get it wrong.

Comment: thanks for your answer it help me in better understanding

Comment: Good point Richard, I neglected to mention that. The OpenSSL library is also a good source for a cryptographically strong random number generator.

Answer (score 5):

What is a true random function?  Last I checked, computers couldn't do that :)

As to why you are getting the same set of numbers each time, it's because you need to seed the built in number generator with some starting 'random' value.  There are many places to get this, but some tend to look good, but turn out bad.  In our games, we generally seed with tic time from game bootup until the first or second user input. User input will always vary across many tics and can therefore be used as a decent starting point.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Microsoft compiler, you can use rand_s, which generates very good random numbers (as good as you can get with only a computer): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxtz2fa8%28VS.80%29.aspx

You can also use `/dev/urandom` on Linux and `CryptGenRandom()` on Windows to get quality random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

or put srand() at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow on from the disucussion on "True" random numbers.  As already, stated any generator that has a seed has a predictable period - I believe it can be 2^48.

If that level of randomness you can use the following:

```
long randomLong(unsigned int x) 
{
    x ^= (x << 21); // x is a non zero seed value
    x ^= (x >> 35);
    x ^= (x << 4);
    return x;
}
```

This is taken from the following paper:
http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper

Which is a really interesting paper describing some low cost random number generators